# How to for loop to find the value you looking for and then add CSS class?

Tags: javascript, loops

```
I'm trying to:
```

1. **for loop**' trough **'colorCard'** and find the **'div class="card'** element with the value: **'color: red'** .
   2. Then add class of **'red'** on this  **'div class="card"'** element

Basicaly my **for loop** function is not working and has no error messages in console.

//MY HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container" id="all-cards">
    </div>
</body>
```

//MY JAVASCRIPT

```
let **colorCard** = [
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: red'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'}
    ];

const allCards = document.querySelector('#all-cards');

let card = colorCard.map(function(cardData){
    return '**<div class="card">**'  +
    '<span>' + cardData.color  + '<span>' +
            '</div>';
});

allCards.innerHTML = card.join('\n');
```

//UP TO HERE MY CODE IS WORKING

//function below is not working.

```
// Loop trough the 'let colorCard' finds the value of "color: red" then add CSS class of "red"

for( i = 0; i < card.length; i++){
    if(card[i] === "color: red"){
        console.log("Found it") 
        //Also I want to add a class on this card object
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to find it by text

```js
const colorCard = [
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: red'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'}
];

const allCards = document.querySelector('#all-cards');
allCards.innerHTML = colorCard
  .map(cardData => `<div class="card"><span>${cardData.color}<span></div>`)
  .join("");

[...document.querySelectorAll(".card span")]
  .filter(ele => ele.textContent === "color: red") // whatever text the span contains
  .forEach(ele => ele.classList.add("yellow"));
```

```css
.red {color:red;} 
.yellow { background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<div id="all-cards"></div>
```

Here is how to add the variable to the class of the div to find it back

```js
const colorCard = [
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: red'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'},
    {  color: 'color: none'}
];

const allCards = document.querySelector('#all-cards');
allCards.innerHTML = colorCard
  .map(cardData => `<div class="card ${cardData.color}"><span>${cardData.color}<span></div>`)
  .join("");

document.querySelector(".red span").classList.add('yellow');
```

```css
.red {color:red;} 
.yellow { background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<div id="all-cards"></div>
```

Comment: not workin: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'card' has already been declared

Comment: I renamed it -- Uncaught ReferenceError: cardData is not defined

Comment: Oh wow, that's great also has less code. 
Can you please explain me what you did here so I can understand more in depth?

Comment: Where do you declare to look for the value "color: red" ?

Comment: I understand that you added the class but how did you add the class on that specific div? 
How did you select the div with the value (color: color:red) and added class on it?

Comment: why does the querySelector (".red") have to match with const colorCard = [
    {  color: 'color: red'}, for the code to work?

I have tried to change querySelector to  (".bright-red") .

I want to be able detect the value and any class i want.

Comment: That is exaclty what I was looking for !
mplungjan thank you for your time and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

- Loop through `allCards.children` (*which returns all the card nodes*) and then check if the `innerText` matches `"color: red"`.
- Then add class to matched element using `classList.add`.

```js
let colorCard=[{color:"color: none"},{color:"color: none"},{color:"color: none"},{color:"color: none"},{color:"color: red"},{color:"color: none"},{color:"color: none"},{color:"color: none"}];

const allCards = document.querySelector('#all-cards');

let card = colorCard.map(function(cardData) {
  return '<div class="card">' +
    '<span>' + cardData.color + '<span>' +
    '</div>';
});

allCards.innerHTML = card.join('\n');

const cards = allCards.children;
for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  if (cards[i].innerText.trim() === "color: red") {
    console.log("Found it")
    cards[i].classList.add("blue");
  }
}
```

```css
.blue {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container" id="all-cards">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what you did here so I can google it to undertant more..

Comment: `allCards` is the container that contains all the card elements and you can get all its children nodes using `.children` and loop over these children nodes and use `innerText` to get the text of these nodes and then match it with the desired text. You can google about `children`, `innerText` and `classList`. @PaulC

Comment: @PaulC I saw you accepted this answer then accepted some other answer, could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: Because once my script was working correctly, it was much more elegant